# Replacing x values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f (x) = (2x^2 -4x +2)$

Find $\frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t-x } $

Answer is  $2t + 2x - 4$  but I am unable to get there

Comment: Can you identify with what part of the question you have problem with?

Comment: Why not?  What is the issue?  $\frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t-x} = \frac{(2t^2 - 4t + 2)-(2x^2 - 4x +2)}{t-x}$.  The rest is ... doing math.  So what can I do to help make it easier for you?

Comment: I have ''succesfully'' factored the upper portion to $t(2t-4)-x(2x-4)$ and I dont know where to go from there

Comment: It's the 'doing math' part that I can't do

Comment: Actually, I don't think that *is* the answer.

Comment: I have to take care of something... try to factor (t -x) out of the top.  I'll be back in 20 minutes or so.

Comment: oh I figured it out

$2t^2-2x^2-4t+4x$

that's $(2t+2x) (t-x)-4(t-x)$

Which in turn is $(2t+2x-4)(t-x)$

And you cancel the $(t-x)$'s !

Math is fun

Comment: Okay on the numerator we have $2t^2 -2x^2x +4t-4x=2 (t^2-x^2) +4 (t-x) = ... $  ah there it is!  Do you see it?

Comment: Factoring can sometimes be pain in the ass.  In this case there was a clever trick to see.  But if you don't see it, and worse comes to worse, you can always factor by "long division" to get a polynomial and rational function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x} &= \frac{(2t^2-4t+2)-(2x^2-4x+2)}{t-x} \\
  &= \frac{2(t^2-x^2)-4(t-x)}{t-x} \\
  &= \frac{2(t+x)\color{red}{(t-x)}-4\color{red}{(t-x)}}
          {\color{red}{t-x}} \\
  &= \frac{\color{red}{(t-x)}[2(t+x)-4]}
          {\color{red}{t-x}} \\
  &= \frac{2(t+x)-4}{1} \\
  &= 2t+2x-4 \\
  &= 2(t+x-4)
\end{align*}

Comment: I liked that answer until the last part.. But I see how you did it.

I actually figured it out by using another method. I like this one better though.

Comment: fixed it (yn) :-P

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say that you've rewritten the numerator as $t(2t-4)-x(2x-4)$.  This is a good start.  Next, let's do something strange and add a particular term to our expression while also subtracting this term.  That is, let's write
\begin{equation}
t(2t-4)-x(2x-4) = t(2t-4)+2tx-x(2x-4)-2tx.
\end{equation}
We can put these extra terms into our parentheses:
\begin{equation}
t(2t-4)+2tx-x(2x-4)-2tx = t(2t+2x-4) - x(2t+2x-4).
\end{equation}
Do you see how this helps?  Putting this expression over $t-x$ should lead you to the desired answer.

Comment: I don't have time to process this information right now, but I'm definitely coming back this weekend to learn how you did it. I did it another way and got it, but your way seems like it's going to make me learn something new. Thanks for the share!

Comment: Happy to help.  To be fair to Ng Chung Tak, I should point out that you can only accept one answer to a question.  If you found both of our solutions helpful, you can upvote them both, but when you accepted my answer you "un-accepted" Ng Chung Tak's answer.  Welcome to MSE!

Comment: Ah! Thanks, still learning how this site works! I would say I've probably wasted more time than I want to admit on learning mathjax while I had plenty of homework on the side, but thanks for the info +++